# Duplicates: “Yesterday Was Monday” versus “A Matter of Minutes”

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We seem to have a bit of a tangled situation with [story-identification] questions involving the Theodore Sturgeon short story “Yesterday was Monday” and the 1986 *Twilight Zone* episode “A Matter of Minutes” that was based on the story.

At the moment, [SF Short Story about resetting the world every day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246796/sf-short-story-about-resetting-the-world-every-day) (which appears to be about the Sturgeon story) is marked as a duplicate of [Looking for an old SF tv short story about blue men staging the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future) (which somewhat confusingly describes a “SF TV short story,” but includes elements—particularly the blue men—that definitely seem to point to “A Matter of Minutes”), marked in turn as a duplicate of [80s or 90s TV episode where a man trapped between two seconds sees world deconstructed and rebuilt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203219/80s-or-90s-tv-episode-where-a-man-trapped-between-two-seconds-sees-world-deconst) which is definitely about the television episode.

I think that the first question ([SF Short Story about resetting the world every day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246796/sf-short-story-about-resetting-the-world-every-day)) should not be a duplicate at all, since it is about the original story, not the episode of *The Twilight Zone*.  Part of the reason for the confusion may be that accepted answer to the second question is:

> That's Theodore Sturgeon's short story "Yesterday was Monday", which inspired the New Twilight Zone episode "A Matter of Minutes"

even though the question is really asking for “A Matter of Minutes,” not “Yesterday Was Monday.”  I would also be inclined to rewrite this answer to correct this confusing point.  What does everyone else think?

Comment: I agree; a short story is not a duplicate of a TV show.  I think "TV short story" is just for lack of good terminology to describe a TV episode, as opposed to a TV movie.

Answer (score 13):

You're not wrong. This question ([1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246796/sf-short-story-about-resetting-the-world-every-day)) is asking about the short story. The other two questions ([2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future), [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203219/80s-or-90s-tv-episode-where-a-man-trapped-between-two-seconds-sees-world-deconst)) are asking about the TV episode.

2 and 3 are clearly duplicates of each other. 1 isn't, so I've un-duped it (and also tidied all of them up because I have some sort of weird compulsive disorder).

Comment: I've also found another dupe of the short story [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181814/man-wakes-up-too-soon-and-scene-isnt-set/181865?noredirect=1)